# How can I login? Black screen

Tags: login, evolution

[image: black screen]

This happened after uninstalling evolution using Stacer. I have tried restarting but even while paying attention to the caps lock warning I can't login. I remember disabling the caps lock key sometime ago.
I can't get terminal to open either. What to do?
Thanks

Comment: You probably deleted "Ubuntu desktop". You should be able to log in with your normal **user name** and **password** using this text terminal and run `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`. You may encounter problems with keyboard layout; so I advise you to test by typing your password in the **login:** prompt (_without pressing the Enter key of course!_) and see if you are typing it correctly.

Comment: What exactly did you install when you meant evolution; there is the `evolution` MUA (*mail user agent application*) which is optional, and the Evolution Data Server which is essential for GNOME (GNOME cannot run without it).  There are two apps using the name evolution in their name within the GNOME project which are very different.

Comment: Ah, so I erased one file too many when I got sick of the Evolution mail server not syncing my calendar. I reinstalled Ubuntu, what fun.

Comment: Don't forget you can re-install Ubuntu Desktop without losing any user configs, and having the *manually installed* packages you added to your system (*where from Ubuntu repositories*) automatically re-install during the installation (*internet must be available for the download*).  A re-install needn't be that big of a problem  (*though 3rd party apps can increase complexity*)

Answer (score 0):

Alt + Ctrl + f7 will switch you to normal screen login

you have also to type your user name in the black screen then the password if you have a password.

Comment: Nope. I reinstalled Ubuntu, But thanks.

Comment: You are welcome , to show it again Alt+ctrl+f1 , to back to normal screen Alt+ Ctrl+ F7